# Tab Bar Titles missing when refactor to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

This is not a big issue, just wondering if there is a way to resolve this

Refactoring to there own boards removes the titles from the main board

[image]

The title is set in the other storyboard, but doesn't show in the main view.

[image]

I assume this is yet to be implemented by Apple as this is a new Xcode feature.

Answer (score 1):

Seems manual is the way from within your storyboard

[image]